# How do I know WHEN a file was locked in SVN?

Tags: svn

I would like to know **when** somebody locked a file in an SVN repository, to tell if he is really using the locked file (according to team policies) or forgot to unlock the file.

Log shows only latest modifications, not actions such as locks.

I'm using both Eclipse SVN and TortoiseSVN

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a link to the "Version Control With Subversion" book that discusses this exact thing:

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.advanced.locking.html#svn.advanced.locking.discovery

Comment: I realize my answer was for the CLI and you're using Eclipse/TortoiseSVN.  Both of these GUIs have a way to get the same information via the "Properties" menu entries.

Comment: Don't worry. There is a CLI client for Windows too!

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways :

- `svn status -u` file
- `svn info file`

where `file` is the file you want to check whether it is locked.